# Newtonsoft.Json v11 - DeserializeObject throws JsonReaderException

Tags: c#, json, json.net

We have upgraded Newtonsoft.Json from 10.0.3 to 11.0.1 and code that has been working previously does not work anymore.

We have following JSON:

```
[{"mail-type":"registration","response":"250 OK id=1UjnNr-gdf-C0 ","invoice-id":,"email":"testuser08@test.com"}]
```

and we call following method:

```
var events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Event[]>(jsonEvents);
```

This worked fine on 10.0.3, but does not on 11.0.1. On this version following exception is thrown:

> Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: An undefined token is not a valid
>   System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]. Path '[0].invoice-id', line 1.

I tried to pass following options to `DeserializeObject`

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
};
```

But still the same error. What changes have to be done to make it work on 11.0.1. I am affraid we cannot accomodate JSON output as this comes from third party API.

Comment: Not sure exactly what changed or why, but your JSON is not well-formed.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will see the following error: `Error: Parse error on line 4: ...0 ", "invoice-id": ,Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got ','`.  I.e. the property `"invoice-id": ,` isn't a well-formed JSON property.

Comment: @dbc thanks, I am aware of this. Unfortunately creation of this JSON is out of my hands and I need to parse it. Anyway, previous versions were able to deserialize it so there must be something to accomplish it in new version too.

Comment: I see it as: previous versions had a bug which allowed to parse malformed json, like yours. In newer version this bug is fixed. So I don't see why "there must be something to accomplish it in new version too".

Comment: @Evk i think so. but as i stated, this invalid JSON is not created in our app, but we need to handle with that. so finding a way to deal with it would be great (e.g. writing custom resolver or set some property in options to ignore such invalid data)

Comment: Looks like the change is documented in the [release notes](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/11.0.1): *Fix - Fixed not erroring when reading undefined for nullable long*.  I just tested Json.NET 10.0, and it appears that using `int?` for the invoice ID would result in an exception, but using `long?` for the invoice ID would result in a null value.  In 11.0 `int?` and `long?` both throw exceptions.

Comment: @dbc we use long? for InvoiceId and it worked in 10.0 - anyway, I am afraid we have to end up in some custom resolver

Comment: So if 10.x works and 11.x doesn't work. What features of 11.x do you need, so that the upgrade is needed from your side? If there is nothing (beside the reason, that you like to always run the latest version), why not stick to 10.x? Maybe in a later version this will be addressed and you can simply switch or you stay on a version that works for you (or the third party changes its serializer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON sample is not well-formed.  If I upload your JSON to https://jsonlint.com/ then the following error is generated:

> ```
> Error: Parse error on line 4:
> ...0 ",   "invoice-id": , "email": "testuse
> ----------------------^
> Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got ','
> ```

The line in question is as follows:

```
"invoice-id": ,
```

According to the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) there needs to be a value between the `:` and the `,`.  But, why did this work in Json.NET 10.0?  Apparently it was a bug, which was fixed.  According to the [11.0.1 release notes](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/11.0.1):

> Fix - Fixed not erroring when reading undefined for nullable **long**

So if we assume that your `Event` type looks like this:

```
public partial class Event
{
    [JsonProperty("invoice-id")]
    public long? InvoiceId { get; set; }

    // Other properties as required
}
```

Then in 10.0 your JSON could be deserialized successfully using this type, but in 11.0 it cannot.  If, however, we change `InvoiceId` to be an `int?`:

```
public partial class Event
{
    [JsonProperty("invoice-id")]
    public int? InvoiceId { get; set; }

    // Other properties as required
}
```

It fails in both versions.  Thus the fix appears to have been to handle `int?` and `long?` consistently.

Ideally, you should ask whoever sent you such JSON to fix it so that it is well-formed as defined by http://www.json.org/ and [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259).  If you nevertheless need to parse such JSON in the same manner as Json.NET 10.0, you could introduce `TolerantNullableLongConverter` as follows:

```
public class TolerantNullableLongConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(long?);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Undefined)
            return null;
        if (reader.Value is long)
            return reader.Value;
        // string or int or decimal or ...
        return serializer.Deserialize<long>(reader);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And apply it to your type as follows:

```
public partial class Event
{
    [JsonProperty("invoice-id")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TolerantNullableLongConverter))]
    public long? InvoiceId { get; set; }

    // Other properties as required
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement workaround with custom converter:

```
internal class NullableLongFixupConverter : JsonConverter {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        writer.WriteValue(value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        // if token undefined - return null
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Undefined)
            return null;
        // otherwise - value
        return (long?) reader.Value;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return objectType == typeof(long?);
    }
}
```

Then you can either decorate properties with it:

```
class Event {
    [JsonProperty("invoice-id")]        
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NullableLongFixupConverter))]
    public long? InvoiceId { get; set; }
}
```

or register globally (will be invoked only for properties of type `long?`):

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () =>
{
    var s = new JsonSerializerSettings();                    
    s.Converters.Add(new NullableLongFixupConverter());
    return s;
};
```